# Is ElasticSearch suited for retrieving a very large number of search records?

Tags: elasticsearch

So, our production environment has an ES cluster that contains all our products inventory (ID and attributes) where each product is mapped to one document. Internally, one of our use cases is to create a logical grouping of these products based on text matching on a bunch of these product attributes.

Often times, it's possible that a product set could contain a very large number of products, say, 5 million. That is, the query to create a product set could match about 5 million documents.

Now, my question is, is ES capable of handling such large retrievals of documents, or is it recommended to use a backing store like Cassandra or HBase to fetch a huge number of documents? Note that I'm not concerned about realtime use cases - I'm okay with having an asynchronous execution of the product set creation, so latency isn't a major concern for me. From what I understand, ES provides the [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/scroll-api.html) to retrieve a large number of documents, but, I'm approaching the problem more from a school of thought perspective.

Is it fine to use ES to fetch very large documents, in the range of 5-10 million? Or should we use a parallel DB with big data capabilities to fetch the data and use ES only as the search store?

Comment: if you don't have issue with latency you can use Scroll API and it doesn't matter for elasticsearch. I've done this huge fetching of data and there was no problem.

Comment: Logical grouping of products (i.e product set) requires you to fetch 5 million documents , logically group them and then upsert/update them back ?

Comment: @SahilGupta I don't need to upsert. I will probably have to write to another database altogether, which isn't a problem in this scope.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR no, it is not meant to retrieve large sets of documents, although you could work your way around with different approaches

notice that Scroll API [might not be suitable for purposes other than re-indexing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#scroll-search-results):

> Scrolling is not intended for real time user requests, but rather for processing large amounts of data, e.g. in order to reindex the contents of one data stream or index into a new data stream or index with a different configuration.

Another way to achieve it would be the [Search after parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after)

> `search_after` is not a solution to jump freely to a random page but rather to scroll many queries in parallel. It is very similar to the `scroll` API but unlike it, the `search_after` parameter is stateless, it is always resolved against the latest version of the searcher. For this reason the sort order may change during a walk depending on the updates and deletes of your index.

Rethink whether your use case *really* needs to exhaustively paginate over large sets of documents. Since ElasticSearch's strength doesn't lie on large result sets.

consult documentation:

- [Paginate search results](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/paginate-search-results.html)
- [index.max_result_window](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/index-modules.html#index-max-result-window)
- [Track total hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/search-your-data.html#track-total-hits)
- [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/scroll-api.html)
- [Search after parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after)

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I want to understand why exactly `ElasticSearch's strength doesn't lie on large result sets.` 
Also, I'm doing exactly what the scroll API is meant to do - for processing large amounts of data. Moving indexes is not the only use case that comes under this bucket, isn't it?